# Why Wikipedia does not have duplicate content issues with search engines?

Tags: duplicate-content

I discovered that the following 2 URLs are serving exactly same content.
Why is this not impacting Wikipedia's SEO?
I've heard having same content across 2 URLs has negative impact on SEO.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Data_mining

Disclaimer: I'm a developer, not in SEO or marketing so don't know much about SEO.

Comment: As the linked question explains, small amounts of internally duplicated content won't hurt your site's rankings.

Comment: The 2 pages I mentioned are entirely identical. And I did not ask how I can do that on my website, just that how Wikipedia has implemented. It's different from the question to marked as duplicate to. Anyway, I found the answer, the robots.txt has /w/ disallowed. This reminds me why I should not post questions to stackexchange anymore. Blind people have become moderators here!!!